# Titanium error loading a webview

Tags: asynchronous, webview, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem with the contents of a webview. I'll explain:
I created a webview

```
var advisor = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'advisor.html'
});
```

whose url is an html inside which there one async script that should provide me with a banner ad (I was provided by those who have commissioned me the job and it works!)

This is the script

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="1" data-revive-id="a8fd1f1dd1d9f38931672573f40cf0b1"></ins> 
<script async src="//mysite.com/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

when I run the app, the webview me the charge, but by an error on loading the php script files.

```
Error loading /www/delivery/asyncjs.php
```

Help me please!